# Unity3D build for IOS simulator in XCode displays a black screen and an error in the console Renderer: Null Device

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to solve the problem with the simulator in XCode for 3 days, when I try to run the project in the iPhone simulator after a successful build, I just get a black screen with problems in the console that won't fix in any way, I tried changing Unity versions to 2019.3, 2020.3 LTS, 2021 LTS, 2023.1, on all the same problem, SDK in the player settings I use the Simulator SDK. Full text of the error:

```
2022-09-12 15:07:15.823493-0700 TestProject3[7410:222456] Built from 'trunk' branch, Version '2023.1.0a9 (b67b5a2b1f70)', Build type 'Development', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp'
2022-09-12 15:07:15.832430-0700 TestProject3[7410:222456] MemoryManager: Using 'Dynamic Heap' Allocator.
[UnityMemory] Configuration Parameters - Can be set up in boot.config
    "memorysetup-bucket-allocator-granularity=16"
    "memorysetup-bucket-allocator-bucket-count=8"
    "memorysetup-bucket-allocator-block-size=4194304"
    "memorysetup-bucket-allocator-block-count=1"
    "memorysetup-main-allocator-block-size=16777216"
    "memorysetup-thread-allocator-block-size=16777216"
    "memorysetup-gfx-main-allocator-block-size=16777216"
    "memorysetup-gfx-thread-allocator-block-size=16777216"
    "memorysetup-cache-allocator-block-size=4194304"
    "memorysetup-typetree-allocator-block-size=2097152"
    "memorysetup-profiler-bucket-allocator-granularity=16"
    "memorysetup-profiler-bucket-allocator-bucket-count=8"
    "memorysetup-profiler-bucket-allocator-block-size=4194304"
    "memorysetup-profiler-bucket-allocator-block-count=1"
    "memorysetup-profiler-allocator-block-size=16777216"
    "memorysetup-profiler-editor-allocator-block-size=1048576"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-main=4194304"
    "memorysetup-job-temp-allocator-block-size=2097152"
    "memorysetup-job-temp-allocator-block-size-background=1048576"
    "memorysetup-job-temp-allocator-reduction-small-platforms=262144"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-background-worker=32768"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-job-worker=262144"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-preload-manager=262144"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-nav-mesh-worker=65536"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-audio-worker=65536"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-cloud-worker=32768"
    "memorysetup-temp-allocator-size-gfx=262144"
-> applicationDidFinishLaunching()
Found 1 interfaces on host : 0) 192.168.137.129
Multi-casting "[IP] 192.168.137.129 [Port] 55000 [Flags] 2 [Guid] 474707957 [EditorId] 0 [Version] 1048832 [Id] iPhonePlayer(8,MacBook-Pro-Dima.local):56000 [Debug] 0 [PackageName] iPhonePlayer [ProjectName] <no name>" to [225.0.0.222:54997]...
On Simulator, Metal is supported only from iOS 13, and it requires at least macOS 10.15 and Xcode 11. Setting no graphics device.
 
Setting UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to NO is no longer supported.
Apple actively discourages that, and all application-wide methods of changing status bar appearance are deprecated
 
-> applicationDidBecomeActive()
[Subsystems] Discovering subsystems at path /Users/dima/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F93E4CD4-55F0-4D67-BE1E-BEFD20B29DA2/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F1B3FD1E-5029-4330-B6A5-ED8A58EE6E67/TestProject3.app/Data/UnitySubsystems
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1; jobified=0
NullGfxDevice:
    Version:  NULL 1.0 [1.0]
    Renderer: Null Device
    Vendor:   Unity Technologies
Initialize engine version: 2023.1.0a9 (b67b5a2b1f70)
2022-09-12 15:07:16.716288-0700 TestProject3[7410:222760] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x600002578820> F8BB3C25-BAE8-11D5-9C31-00034315CD46
ERROR: Shader Hidden/Universal Render Pipeline/Sampling shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
ERROR: Shader Hidden/Universal Render Pipeline/LutBuilderLdr shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
ERROR: Shader Hidden/Universal Render Pipeline/LutBuilderHdr shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
ERROR: Shader Hidden/Universal Render Pipeline/UberPost shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
ERROR: Shader Hidden/Universal Render Pipeline/Debug/DebugReplacement shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
ERROR: Shader Hidden/Light2D-Shape shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
ERROR: Shader Hidden/Light2D-Shape-Volumetric shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
ERROR: Shader Hidden/Light2D-Point shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
ERROR: Shader Hidden/Light2d-Point-Volumetric shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
ERROR: Shader Hidden/ShadowProjected2D shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
ERROR: Shader Hidden/Shadow2DShadowSprite shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
ERROR: Shader Hidden/Shadow2DUnshadowSprite shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
ERROR: Shader Hidden/Shadow2DUnshadowGeometry shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/Universal Render Pipeline/FallbackError' - All subshaders removed
WARNING: Shader Did you use #pragma only_renderers and omit this platform?
WARNING: Shader If subshaders removal was intentional, you may have forgotten turning Fallback off?
ERROR: Shader Hidden/Universal Render Pipeline/FallbackError shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/Universal Render Pipeline/FallbackError' - All subshaders removed
WARNING: Shader Did you use #pragma only_renderers and omit this platform?
WARNING: Shader If subshaders removal was intentional, you may have forgotten turning Fallback off?
ERROR: Shader Hidden/Universal Render Pipeline/Stop NaN shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
ERROR: Shader Hidden/Universal Render Pipeline/SubpixelMorphologicalAntialiasing shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
ERROR: Shader Hidden/Universal Render Pipeline/GaussianDepthOfField shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
ERROR: Shader Hidden/Universal Render Pipeline/BokehDepthOfField shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
ERROR: Shader Hidden/Universal Render Pipeline/CameraMotionBlur shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
ERROR: Shader Hidden/Universal Render Pipeline/PaniniProjection shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
ERROR: Shader Hidden/Universal Render Pipeline/Bloom shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
ERROR: Shader Hidden/Universal Render Pipeline/TemporalAA shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
ERROR: Shader Hidden/Universal Render Pipeline/LensFlareDataDriven shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
ERROR: Shader Hidden/Universal Render Pipeline/Scaling Setup shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
ERROR: Shader Hidden/Universal Render Pipeline/Edge Adaptive Spatial Upsampling shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
ERROR: Shader Hidden/Universal Render Pipeline/FinalPost shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
ERROR: Shader Sprites/Default shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
ERROR: Shader Sprites/Mask shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Universal Render Pipeline/Lit' - All subshaders removed
WARNING: Shader Did you use #pragma only_renderers and omit this platform?
WARNING: Shader If subshaders removal was intentional, you may have forgotten turning Fallback off?
ERROR: Shader Universal Render Pipeline/Lit shader is not supported on this GPU (none of subshaders/fallbacks are suitable)
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Universal Render Pipeline/Lit' - All subshaders removed
WARNING: Shader Did you use #pragma only_renderers and omit this platform?
WARNING: Shader If subshaders removal was intentional, you may have forgotten turning Fallback off?
UnloadTime: 0.939870 ms
2022-09-12 15:07:17.413547-0700 TestProject3[7410:222456] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <SplashScreenController: 0x7f8f71f77bc0>.
```

I've also tried using BuildIn, and it's the same there, please help.
P.S the build server checkbox is disabled.

Comment: Could you please provide the following data: macOS version, iOS version, Xcode version.

Comment: Yes, macOs: Monterey 12.6, XCode version: 14.0(14A309), I don't have an iOS device, I wanted to test any versions through the emulator

Answer (score 0):

> **On Simulator, Metal is supported only from iOS 13, and it requires at
> least macOS 10.15 and Xcode 11. Setting no graphics device.**

If possible, update all of your software to the required version, otherwise it would not possible to run your game on the simulator.

Comment: So, I have versions higher than you indicated, maybe I don't have Metal support on the VM?

Comment: Correct, your VM doesn't provide metal-compatible virtual hardware.

Comment: Is there any way to add compatibility?

Comment: AFAIK, it’s not possible.

Comment: Aaaaaaaah, F xD